# Need to better understand lists in R

Tags: r

So I am using a package in R called `twitteR`

```
consumer_key <- "MY API KEY"
consumer_secret <- "MY API KEY"
access_token <- "MY API KEY"
access_secret <- "MY API KEY"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,
                    consumer_secret,
                    access_token,
                    access_secret)

tweets<-searchTwitter('NASA',n=3200,lang = 'en')
```

Now I have list called tweets

```
> length(tweets)
[1] 3200
```

Looking at the first few elements

```
> tweets[1:3]
[[1]]
[1] "PepperAlbo: RT @mashable: NASA researchers reinvented the wheel"

[[2]]
[1] "UnitedStatesTD: NASA to release Voyager Golden Record as a vinyl box set - via @UnitedStatesTD "

[[3]]
[1] "ISSAboveYou: Hello @Space_Station from The Vails of Long Beach CA 302.0 mi away @NASA_Johnson #issabove "
```

Clearly the tweets are in lists within list, so lets say I call on the first element

```
> tweets[[1]]
[1] "PepperAlbo: RT @mashable: NASA researchers reinvented the wheel "
```

But there is actually more to the list

```
> str(tweets[[1]])
Reference class 'status' [package "twitteR"] with 17 fields
 $ text         : chr "RT @mashable: NASA researchers reinvented the wheel "
 $ favorited    : logi FALSE
 $ favoriteCount: num 0
 $ replyToSN    : chr(0) 
 $ created      : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-11-29 01:07:18"
 $ truncated    : logi FALSE
 $ replyToSID   : chr(0) 
 $ id           : chr "935676507661524992"
 $ replyToUID   : chr(0) 
 $ statusSource : chr "<a href=\"" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>"
 $ screenName   : chr "PepperAlbo"
 $ retweetCount : num 685
 $ isRetweet    : logi TRUE
 $ retweeted    : logi FALSE
 $ longitude    : chr(0) 
 $ latitude     : chr(0) 
 $ urls         :'data.frame':  0 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ url         : chr(0) 
  ..$ expanded_url: chr(0) 
  ..$ dispaly_url : chr(0) 
  ..$ indices     : num(0) 
 and 53 methods, of which 39 are  possibly relevant:
   getCreated, getFavoriteCount, getFavorited, getId, getIsRetweet, getLatitude, getLongitude, getReplyToSID, getReplyToSN, getReplyToUID, getRetweetCount,
   getRetweeted, getRetweeters, getRetweets, getScreenName, getStatusSource, getText, getTruncated, getUrls, initialize, setCreated, setFavoriteCount,
   setFavorited, setId, setIsRetweet, setLatitude, setLongitude, setReplyToSID, setReplyToSN, setReplyToUID, setRetweetCount, setRetweeted, setScreenName,
   setStatusSource, setText, setTruncated, setUrls, toDataFrame, toDataFrame#twitterObj
```

using one of them

```
> tweets[[1]]$id
[1] "935676507661524992"
```

So my question is where is all of this stored? is it along with the tweet text in the `tweet[[1]]`? So when I call only `tweet[[1]]` why is it that only the tweet gets printed and nothing else?

Is this a special kind of list that is being defined by this `Reference class 'status'` ?

Comment: this is not really a question that belongs here... but anyway. As you say there are Lists in Lists. And the return value is specified somewhere, made up of the `screenName` and the `text`

Comment: This has to do with the `print` method for type of object returned by `searchTwitter`. This is more of an object-oriented issue than a question about lists. See `class(tweets)`.